# Is it possible to show a UIImagePickerController at full screen in iPad?

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm currently working on the iPad version of an app, where I used UIImagePickerController to let the user pick a photo from their library.

In the iPad an error message suggests using a popover, but I can't show my imagepicker at fullscreen. Is it possible?

I'm being told that it can be done using presentModalViewController. If so can anyone point me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Only Popovers can be used to do it, full screen is not possible.

Comment: Although is not supposed to be used or working, this works in iOS7 and iOS8 on the iPad:
UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
pickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 4):

It is possible!

Just remove this:

```
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:frame
                                   inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                 animated:YES];
```

And use this instead:

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Where picker is your UIImagePickerController.

Comment: `presentModalViewController:animated:` was deprecated starting in iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift:** It is possible by changing `modalPresentationStyle`.

```
@IBAction func openPhotoLibrary(_sender:UIButton){
  if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary){return}

  let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
  imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
  imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
  imagePicker.delegate = self
  imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

  self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```